# Android 11 Media player not working , Android SDK 30

Tags: android, cordova, android-11, cordova-media-plugin

After I upgrade to android 11 (API 30), I am getting problem with cordova-plugin-media.
Its not playing audio stream ..
When I click play audio, output was: Error: 1 (which refers to MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED = 1)
I Have an app builder, In which 20K apps that depends on this plugin (required this feature)-
I don't required to record and play.
We use web stream e.g (-[(http://streams.radiobob.de/bob-chillout/aac-64/streams.radiobob.de/)])
and just want to play this audio stream on button click.
Here is config.xml, I am using-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="app.*********" version="3.6.1" android-versionCode="30">
<name>******</name>
<description />
<author href="444656972743" email="">*********</author>
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" 
 />
</feature>
<feature name="SocialSharing">
    <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
</feature>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="1.1.7" />
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <icon src="icons/android-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android-xxhdpi.png" density="fr-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-xxhdpi.png" density="fr-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-xxhdpi.png" density="land-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="splashscreen/android-xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
  </platform>
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://www.youtube.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://player.vimeo.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://player.vimeo.com/*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~5.0.3">
    <variable name="KEEP_AVAUDIOSESSION_ALWAYS_ACTIVE" value="NO" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" source="npm" spec="1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="4.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="1.0.9" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" spec="6.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free" spec="0.14.0" source="npm" />
</widget>
```

I appreciate any solution or workaround..

Comment: It reads `android-versionCode="28"` ...and without a stacktrace of some kind, this question is pointless. Better just follow the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/issues/185

Comment: That was just a typo mistake, I edited, I am using android-versionCode="30"

Comment: If you'd remove `<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />` ...you might eventually realize, that you bark up the wrong one tree. When it cannot cache the stream, it likely will not play it either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new update in https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media to cover the saving file path issue for android 11+.

If you update "/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/media/AudioHandler.java" and "/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/media/AudioPlayer.java" in your project, then it should be working.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/4093f7e14fe65f94ffbef072ed188a0205e78a59/src/android/AudioHandler.java

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/4093f7e14fe65f94ffbef072ed188a0205e78a59/src/android/AudioPlayer.java

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Luckily, there is an official release of cordova-plugin-media that also fix this issue:

[cordova-plugin-media@5.0.4](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2022/01/25/media-plugin-5.0.4-release.html)